# How to databind a dropdownlist at page load

Tags: c#, asp.net

Assuming i have two dropdownlists namely: dropdownlistA and dropdownlistB. at page load, i bind values to dropdownlistA. however, depending on the value selected or displayed in dropdownlistA, i want to bind data to dropdownlistB.

Currently, i can bind data to dropdownlistA alright and i already have the required dataset and datatable bind data to dropdownlist. However, dropdownlistB does not bind at page load since the criteria for filling the dataset to bind dropdownlistB (which is the value of dropdownlistA) is not selected. how can i make this wwork.

I am currently considered if this might work. If i were to call the databind for dropdownlistA in a different declared method besides its binding in page load, and select the value from bind in the declared method, would any value be selected?

For example:
  In during page load, i call the a method that returns dataset values which i bind to dropdownlistA(caseIDDropDownList). then i call another method (CreateexhibitDataSet()) which contains the dataset values for binding dropdownlistB(exhibitDropDownList). however, i need to define a criteria in the CreateExhibitDataset() method which i will use to generate the dataset values to bind dropdownlistB. if i were to call for the data bind of dropdownlistA(caseIDDropdownList) again in the CreateExhibitDataset() method and pick the value in the dropdown list, would i get any values?

How can i work around this to bind both dropdownlists on page load?

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //mgrID = "M510";
        //mgrID = Request.QueryString["mgrID"];
        mgrID = (string)(Session["userID"]);

        if (mgrID != null)
        {
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                CreateCasesDataset();
                DataView caseDataView = new DataView(caseDataSet.Tables[0]);
                caseIDDropDownList.DataSource = caseDataView;
                caseIDDropDownList.DataTextField = "CaseID";
                caseIDDropDownList.DataBind();

                CreateExhibitDataset();

                DataView exhibDataView = new DataView(exhibitDataSet.Tables[0]);
                exhibitsDropDownList.DataSource = exhibDataView;
                exhibitsDropDownList.DataTextField = "ExhibitID";
                exhibitsDropDownList.DataBind();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            string message = "The System couldnt identify you with any ID. Please Log in to access system functions";
            System.Text.StringBuilder sb = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
            sb.Append("<script type = 'text/javascript'>");
            sb.Append("window.onload=function(){");
            sb.Append("alert('");
            sb.Append(message);
            sb.Append("')};");
            sb.Append("</script>");
            ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "alert", sb.ToString());
        }

    }
```

And this is the additional code of the CreateExhibitMethod

```
private void CreateExhibitDataset()
    {
        caseIDDropDownList.DataBind();
        string selectedCaseID = caseIDDropDownList.SelectedValue.ToString();

        SqlConnection exhibitConnection = new SqlConnection(strConn);
        exhibitSqlDataAdapter.SelectCommand = new SqlCommand("SELECT ExhibitID FROM Exhibits WHERE CaseID = '"+selectedCaseID+"'", exhibitConnection);
        exhibitSqlDataAdapter.Fill(exhibitDataSet);
    }
```

Comment: I promise to accept the answer with the thick if it solves my problem...:(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also use the `Page_LoadComplete` event to help accomplish this. It has the benefit of firing after the Load but before other page driven events. I would recommend keeping your bind of DropDownListB in a separate method, then if `!IsPostBack` call that method from the `Page_LoadComplete` method. Otherwise use @WraithNath's idea of calling that method from the `SelectedIndexChanged` event.

Comment: @Joe---thing is i already have a slectedindexchanged for dropdownlistA that automatically binds the list for dropdownlistB. this works fine. but am not sure according to @WraithNath's post how the selected indexchanged could fire when the page has not finished loading so i think you recommendation would work perfect. however how can i declare the page_loadcomplete?

Comment: Works perfectly...but when i use the beak point i realise the value picked from the dropdownlisA is empty."" guess i have to check if any values actually get binded to droopdownlistA

Comment: @Selase - Yes. It's done exactly like the `Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)` except it's `Page_LoadComplete(object sender, EventArgs e)`.

Answer (score 0):

If you set DropDownList A to AutoPostback, then wire up the SelectedIndexChangedEvent.

eg:

```
protected void DropDownListA_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
   //Get value from list A
   string sValue = DropDownListA.SelectedValue.toString();

  //Get the data related to the selected Value in A
  Datatable Data = DataManager.GetList(sValue);

//Bind the list B
 DropDownListB.DataSource = Data;
DropDownListB.DataBind();
}
```

EDIT: if you really want to bind both lists on page load you could store all the values in a javascript array and add and remove values based on the selections but you would have to do it all in javascript

Comment: @ Wra- Thanks for the response..very much appreciated. can this work on page load? i have a similar code for selected index changed for dropdownlistA...how ever this happens at postback. I was looking to do it at form load...also posts back alright but there arent any values displayed in dropdownlistB untill i select another value in dropdownlistA then the selectedindexchanged fires for the dropdownlisA and binds dropdownlListB

Comment: Hi, I wouldnt bind both lists in page load. You would have redundant items in list 2 that would just make the page take longer to render. I would have 1 list item in list B that says something like 'please select an item in list A' This way the list is virtually empty until an item is selected in list A. If you wrap both lists in an asp:UpdatePanel the user wont even notice the postback and the list B will load when an item is selected in A

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't want dropdownlistB to be bound at page load because you do not know which items to bound to.
You can use an asp.UpdatePanel to do this, but this requires you to configure Ajax.
You can also consider jQuery for this:
Bind the change event:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#dropdownlistA').change(getdropdownlistB);
});

 function getdropdownlistB() {
            var ID= $("#getdropdownlistA").attr("value");
 dropdownlistB= $('#dropdownlistB').attr('disabled', true).children('option').remove().end().append('<option value="0">Loading...</option>');

            PageMethod("my.aspx/getdropdownlistBbyID", ["ID", ID], getdropdownlistBResponse)
        }

function PageMethod(wsurl, paramArray, onSuccess) {
            var pagePath = window.location.pathname;
            //Create list of parameters in the form:  
            //{"paramName1":"paramValue1","paramName2":"paramValue2"}  
            var paramList = '';
            if (paramArray.length > 0) {
                for (var i = 0; i < paramArray.length; i += 2) {
                    if (paramList.length > 0) paramList += ',';
                    paramList += '"' + paramArray[i] + '":"' + paramArray[i + 1] + '"';
                }
            }
            paramList = '{' + paramList + '}';
            //Call the page method
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: wsurl,
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                data: paramList,
                dataType: "json",
                async: false,
                success: onSuccess,
                error: function(xhr, status, error) {
                    alert("error")
                }
            });
        }

 function getdropdownlistBResponse(response) {
            var listB= (typeof response.d) == 'string' ? eval('(' + response.d + ')') : response.d;
            var dropdownlistB= $('#dropdownlistB');
            dropdownlistB.attr('disabled', false).children('option').remove();
            if (listB.length == 0) { dropdownlistB.attr('disabled', true).append('<option value="0">Select A...</option>'); }
            for (var i = 0; i < listB.length; i++) {
                var val = listB[i].bVal;
                var text = listB[i].bText;
                var def = listB[i].Default;

                dropdownlistB.append('<option value="' + val + '">' + text + '</option>');
                if (def) { dropdownlistB.val(val); } //set the default
            }

        }
```

Then in the ASPX page you get the data for dropdownlistB:

```
[WebMethod]
        public static List<listB> getdropdownlistBbyID(string ID)
            //called from script to get the dropdownlistB, using the selection ID from dropdownlistA
        {

           .. Insert code to get your data
            List<listB> blist= new List<listB>() { };
            ...Insert code to fill blist with your data with rows of 3 values {ID, text, default yes/no}


            return blist;
        }
```

Answer (score -1):

Try setting the dropdownlistA listindex to the first value (e.g. index = 0) and then fire your auto-fill routine for listB

Comment: @Hor...sounds catchy...where do i set this index? in the page load or when am calling the method to populate the dataset for dropdownlistB?